# Protect routes in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 for my project. I am trying to secure Routes and make sure only logged in user can access certain routes. I am aware about middlewares but I am wondering if anyone post an example or a link explaining about middleware and how to protect a page using middleware.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sajan! Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! To ask helpful questions it is important that they are specific and well defined, and it is appreciated (and expected) to present what you have tried so far. Also, please take some time to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it will help you get the hang of everything. You'll also get a badge ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on the answer given by Joe Rose, you can also specify the middleware in your controller rather than in your `routes.php` file.

E.g you could have your routes set out like

```
Route::get('/example', 'ExampleController@index');
Route::post('/example/post', 'ExampleController@post');
Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
```

And then inside your controller reference it like so:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
    //....
```

If you're looking for more info, check out the link to the docs Joe gave, and also [this blog post](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style) which explains what middleware is really well and how to create your own if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an example how to implement handle function in the Authenticate middleware. I am kind of confused in that part.

Comment: @SajanSilwal By default, Laravel ships with `Authenticate.php` inside the Middleware folder (app/Http/Middleware). 
The handle method checks to see if the user is a guest (i.e not logged in) using this line `if ($this->auth->guest())`, it then checks if the request is an ajax request, if it is it returns a 401 unauthorized message for the request with this line `if ($request->ajax())`, otherwise it returns them to the log in page with `else { return redirect()->guest('auth/login'); }`
Otherwise if you are logged in then you will fail the guest check and your request will carry on as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about using middleware. The included `Auth` middleware is what you should use, as long as you are also using the included `Auth` controller to authenticate users. You would write your route like this:

```
Route::get('/page', array(
    'uses' => 'Controller@method',
    'middleware'=>'auth'
));
```

(The above example is using a `GET` request, but it could other request types, like `POST` for example).

This will use the default behavior of the middleware which checks to see if the user is logged in (authenticated). You can also extend or overwrite the built-in functions to allow you to direct the application on where to send the user if they are or are not logged in, etc. Laravel's official documentation is a good starting point: [link](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)